# Run class in Jar file

Tags: java, command-line, jar

If you have a jar file called `myJar.jar` located in **/myfolder** and you want to use the class called `myClass` from it, how do you go about doing it from the command line?

I thought it would be to go into the directory and say `java -cp myJar.jar.myClass` but that isn't working.

Comment: `java -cp myJar.jar myClass` works fine for me -- do you have a spurious period in your command line instead of a space?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want 'to use' that class? Is there a main method that you want to call in particular?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Use `java -cp myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass`.

1. If the class is not in a package then simply `java -cp myjar.jar myClass`.
2. If you are not within the directory where `myJar.jar` is located, then you can do:

   1. On Unix or Linux platforms:

      `java -cp /location_of_jar/myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass`
   2. On Windows:

      `java -cp c:\location_of_jar\myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass`

Comment: Just adding to it - in case com.mypackage.myClass (in the above example) has dependencies on other jars, run it as follows:           java -cp dependentfile1.jar;dependentfile2.jar;c:\location_of_jar\myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass

Comment: A possible failure path to watch out for in case this doesn't work: be sure your fully qualified path to your class matches exactly what's in your jar file.  If you do unzip -l /location-of-jar/myjar.jar, and see something other than com/mypackage/myClass, this is your problem.   (For instance, if you see bin/com/mypackage/myClass, you should have cd'ed into bin to build your jar file; what you have won't work.)

Comment: use MyClass, not myClass

Comment: By trying the above I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/cli/Main
        at com.company.project.demo.bdd.runner.Execute.main(Execute.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

Comment: if you on linux use ':' instead of ';' for adding dependent jars, the classpath separator ':' is ';' on windows. example:-> java -cp dependentfile1.jar:dependentfile2.jar:c:\location_of_jar\myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass

Answer (score 24):

You want:

```
java -cp myJar.jar myClass
```

The [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) gives the following example:

```
C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses\myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

Answer (score 20):

There are two types of JAR files available in Java:

1. Runnable/Executable jar file which contains manifest file.
   To run a Runnable jar you can use `java -jar fileName.jar` or `java -jar -classpath abc.jar fileName.jar`
2. Simple jar file that does not contain a manifest file so you simply run your main class by giving its path `java -cp ./fileName.jar MainClass`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are in the directory where `myJar.jar` file is and that `myClass` has a `public static void main()` method on it:

You use the following command line:

```
java -cp ./myJar.jar myClass
```

Where:

1. `myJar.jar` is in the **current path**, note that `.` isn't in the current path on most systems. A **fully qualified path** is preferred here as well.
2. `myClass` is a **fully qualified package path** to the class, the example assumes that `myClass` is in the **default package** which is bad practice, if it is in a nested package it would be `com.mycompany.mycode.myClass`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to execute a `.jar`, and whatever one class in that `.jar` should have `main()` and the following are the parameters to it :

```
java -DLB="uk" -DType="CLIENT_IND" -jar com.fbi.rrm.rrm-batchy-1.5.jar
```