# How to run java class from .jar archive?

Tags: java, unix, jar, console

Need to run particular java class from jar package through unix console. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: kindly check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to call a specific method of a class from a terminal.

You can only call the main method with `java -cp JarFile.jar package.ClassName`

Or, if your jar contains a manifest file, then you can do: `java -jar pJarFile.jar`.

Comment: @psed In that case, you have to do `java -cp JarFile.jar package.ClassName` with `package.ClassName` being the class containing the main method.

Comment: Yes, there is a class with "main" method.

Comment: Finally. Works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @psed I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: I am getting could not find or load main class. I am running this in solaris

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
java -cp myJar.jar myClass
```

The **-cp** option is used when setting up the classpath manually ie give full path of location of jar file and then run command

Eg.

```
C:> java -cp C:\java\MyClasses\myJar.jar myClass
```

Comment: Got "NoClassDefFoundException"

Comment: Are quotes for -cp argument needed?

Answer (score 2):

For running a jar file you can have **either** of following approach. Both of them require that you know the fully qualified name of the class where `main(String[] arg)` method is written.

Say your class containing main method is `com.myclass.MainClass`

1. You can run the jar directly. Keep the jar file at the location from where you are running this command

   `java -cp yourjarfile.jar  com.myclass.MainClass`
2. Create a manifest `manifest.mf` file with following content

   `Main-class: com.myclass.MainClass`

now create the jar file as follows

```
   jar -cmf manifest.mf yourjarfile.jar <your class file location>
```

Run this jar with the following command

```
    java -jar yourjarfile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the -jar parameter:

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar
```

Comment: Yep, but jar contains a lot of other java classes.

Comment: Lets say its not a "MyProgram.jar" but "AllMyPrograms.jar" and i need to run "MyFirstProgram.java".

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the specific class file by doing:

```
jar xf MyProgram.jar theclass.class
```

it will end up in your current directory

then just run the classfile

```
java theclass
```

Comment: Is it possible to run without extraction?

Comment: try java -jar MyProgram.jar <package>.theclass