# Running java application in terminal window: No such file or directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I am using Eclipse for java and I just created a program I am trying to run on the terminal window for Mac.  Every time I try to run it I get a No such file or directory.  In the terminal window I moved to the source folder.  Is this where I am supposed to be to run java programs from Eclipse?  My command is listed below with the two text files (in1.txt) and (in2.txt) that have text in them.

```
java Cat in1.txt in2.txt out.txt
```

My code is provided below.

```
public class Cat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Out out = new Out(args[args.length -1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length -1; i++)
    {
        In in = new In(args[i]);
        String s = in.readAll();
        out.println(s);
        in.close();
    }
    out.close();

  }
 }
```

Comment: Check if you can run `java -version` from your terminal.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6780789/2055542

Comment: where? In the terminal?

Comment: We need more information. Where is the file name used ? Print the entire stack trace. Most likely - you need an absolute path for the file name.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_43"

Comment: the file names are in my current project in eclipse

Comment: What are `In` and `Out`? This doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to the directory where `Cat.class` is located before you run the `java` command.