# Creating a jar file from Scala project without using Sbt or Maven

Tags: eclipse, scala

I developed a Scala project using Scala eclipse Ide. How do I get a jar file from this project so that i can run the Scala classes present in the project through command line?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use SBT in order to create an executable jar file. A jar file is essentially only a zip file with a fixed internal structure. A jar file can contain a file "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" with metdata like for instance the main class.

Refer to the [Jar file article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) for more information.

There is a command line tool called "jar" which can help you creating a valid Java Archive.

Comment: I got the jar file containing some scala classes in it .Now, how do I call these from the command line?

Comment: See this post for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file

If you defined a main class in the manifest file, then you can simply run java -jar your-jar-file.jar