# run .jar file asterisk-java

Tags: java, jar, asterisk, fastagi

I created a project wich plays simple ivr prompt, then compiled it and made a jar file. but I don't know how to run it.
I tried alternative way: placed .class files in usr/services/simpleProject/classes path and mapped it correctly then it works. But I need to run it with .jar file, any sugessions?

Comment: `java -jar example.jar` doesn't work?

Comment: Have you got a `manifest` file ?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper no it asks main class

Answer (score -1):

I believe you did't include a **MANIFEST** file in your **jar**. Take a look at [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Alternatively you can run the jar file as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file) without specifying the main class.

Comment: I included MANIFEST file with specifying the main class

Comment: has this main class a `public static void main(String[] aargh)` method?

Comment: Can you show us the manifest file contents? Posting the file structure inside your jar wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps an example would help!

If Unix-based...

```
mkdir mypkg
cat > mypkg/MyClass.java
package mypkg;
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("executing main!");
  }
}
```

[give Control-D]

```
javac mypkg/MyClass.java
cat > manifest.txt
Main-Class: mpkg.MyClass
```

[give Control-D]

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar manifest.txt mypkg/*.class
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Should yield:

executing main!

---

If Windows-based...

```
mkdir mypkg
copy con: mypkg\MyClass.java
package mypkg;
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("executing main!");
  }
}
```

[give Control-Z]

```
javac mypkg\MyClass.java
copy con: manifest.txt
Main-Class: mpkg.MyClass
```

[give Control-Z]

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar manifest.txt mypkg\*.class
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Should yield:

executing main!