# running sbt class using only a jar

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, scopt

Is there any way to run sbt commands with only a jar instead of a project?

I've been having issues using scopt with java or scala commands, and it only seems to work with sbt.

Ideally something like

```
sbt --jar <jar name>/"run-main <options"
```

Comment: Perhaps you may want to share the issues you're having with scopt, using the java command is more portable and you may want to consider it.

Comment: I don't think you need SBT to do that. You can just use java. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6780789/1553233) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to package everything up into something you can execute. One possibility would be to create a fat jar using something like [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

Once you've built your jar, you can then:

`java -jar /path/to.jar --your-options`

Take note that at this point you can only do what would have been the equivalent of `sbt run-main` with the jar. You cannot of course invoke any of the other sbt commands on the jar created.