# Use ProcessBuilder to capture output of separate package

Tags: java, processbuilder, java-threads

I have a project that uses ProcessBuilder to capture the output of the command "java -jar someJar.jar -argument", but have now moved the jar's source files to a separate package; somepackage. The package has a main function, so I would like to create a ProcessBuilder that captures the output of that process, as if it were a different Thread.

Is this possible, or will I have to completely re-write the code to allow it to use the source files instead of the binary?

Comment: You are mixing the terms in a confusing way. What do you mean with “have now moved the jar's source files to a separate package”? And why does this raise the desire to run “source files instead of the binary” (which is, of course, impossible without compiling them)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm assuming right, the package has main function and we are trying to get output of the main method that executes with `java -jar processbuilder` command.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(your java -jar command);     
Process process = pb .start();
process.waitFor();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
int jwtOytputBytesRead = 0;
String Output = "";
while ((jwtOytputBytesRead = in.read(contents)) != -1) {
            Output += new String(contents, 0, jwtOytputBytesRead);
    }
System.out.println(Output);
```

Try this link as well to specify the main the class
[Run class in Jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but it needs to be threaded, because I need to constantly be getting the output from it.

Comment: how about Trying callable in 
java.             Example: public class ProcessBuilderProcessor implements Callable<Integer>{}                                                     Then use executor   ProcessBuilderProcessor pbp=new ProcessBuilderProcessor("");
  ExecutorService executr = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  Future<Integer> future1 = executr.submit(pbp);