# How to run a java code inside a jar file that reads a file specified in String args[]

Tags: java, gradle, jar

So I have a java program that reads a file specified by using args

```
$ java Main somefile.txt
```

But how do I do it when I make it into a jar? Let's say that foo.jar contains

```
-META-INF
-Main.class
-someFile.txt
```

And run it with (without specifying args after)

java -jar foo.jar

How do I do that? Note that I also use gradle to assemble the jar.

Comment: `java -jar foo.jar somefile.txt`

Comment: "_(without specifying args after)_", the same way you would do with the build code without the args `java Main` by using a constant in the code or by getting every file in the folder.

Comment: or by specifying the argument(s) in a properties (text) file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple approaches.

- You can provide a [Manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) inside your jar file that tells the 'java' command what class to launch. This is called "[setting the application entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)" in the Java tutorial. Then

  java -jar foo.jar src/sourceSets/resources/someFile.txt
- You can also [tell java to run your particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file) from the jar file:

  java -cp foo.jar Main src/sourceSets/resources/someFile.txt

  From the comments and edit of the original question, it seems you want to run the java command *without* putting any arguments on that line, *but* *also* have the program receive arguments.  There's not way to do that directly.

Instead, write your own little java program that invokes the original main() routine with the argument value you need:

```
public class MyAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtherProgram.main(String[]{"somefile.txt});
    }

}
```

and then invoke that.

*Somehow* you have to get that "somefile.txt" string in there. if you can't provide it as an argument, you have to provide it in the jar file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough, my problem is if I want to run the jar file without specifying args. Meaning, someFile.txt is inside foo.jar too. Sorry about the confusion.